# Can a child-class use the asignment operator overload of its parent?

Tags: c++, c++11, assignment-operator

I've been asking myself if it's possible to create a base class which has operator-overloads which the child-class(es) could use.

Example (with Template):

```
#include <cassert>

template<typename T>
struct Base {
    T value {};
    Base& operator=(const T& newVal) { this->value = newVal; return *this; }
};

template<typename T>
struct Child : Base<T> {
};

int main() {
    Child<int> ch {};
    assert(ch.value == 0);
    ch = 10;  // compilation error here
    assert(ch.value == 10);
}
```

I tried it myself with a Compile-Error. What should I do if I want to do that? Is this even possible or do I have to use virtual and override it (or
whatever is possible)?

> Error C2679: binary 'operator' : no operator found which takes a
>   right-hand operand of type 'type' (or there is no acceptable
>   conversion)
>
> Compiler: MS Visual C++ 2015

PS: Please tell me if the solution makes the code ugly or not.

Comment: It's usually a good idea to include the *exact* compiler error you get. Also include the compiler name and version.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Every class declares an `operator=`. If you don't do it explicitly, the operator is declared implicitly. That (possibly implicit) declaration *hides* the base member. To unhide it, you need to use a `using` declaration:

```
template <typename T>
struct Child : Base<T>
{
    using Base<T>::operator=;
};
```

Comment: Though such an overload doesn't seem like a terribly good idea.